# Determining a matrix's invertibility with eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A$ be a 4 x 4 matrix with eigenvalues -4, -2, 4, -3.

Then, the determinant of $A$ is the product of all the eigenvalues, which is, -96.

So, how does one determine if a matrix $A-4I$ is invertible or not?

We know that 4 is an eigenvalue of $A$. And the determinant of $A \neq 0$, which means the matrix $A$ is invertible.

Doesn't this mean the matrix $A-4I$ is also invertible? Is there a relationship between the eigenvalues of a matrix with its invertibility?

Comment: If $4$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ so the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda):=\det(A-\lambda I)$  is zero when $\lambda=4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. More generally speaking, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $A-\lambda I$ is **singular**: Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $x$. Observe that $$(A-\lambda I)x=Ax-\lambda Ix=\lambda x-\lambda x=\mathbf{0}=0\cdot x.$$ That is, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A-\lambda I$ with associated eigenvector $x$. We know that if $0$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix, then such matrix has zero determinant and hence is singular.